# NestJS Service with a dependency service, testing a getter from the dependent service

Tags: testing, jestjs, nestjs, ts-jest

I am using Jest to test my NestJS API.  I have a basic controller/service setup, but the service has a dependency for working with the environment.

My application service (AppService.ts) has a number of getters for returning information from the .env file and other environmental settings, as well as other application endpoints.  The AppService uses the .env file (via NestJS ConfigService) and other dependent services to get configuration settings for the API.

On a route, I need to get some of these settings and the service (business logic) on that route that uses the settings to control data validation.  The component module file will import modules (UsersModule, DataEntryModule, ConfigModule, etc...).

I am trying to test the controller's service, which has these configuration values, to ensure the business logic works correctly.

**EDIT** I have modified my sample to simplify the coding and the example. I believe the issue is in my definition of the mock, using createMock() and then trying to spyOn() the getter does not work.

service.ts

```
import { Injectable} from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class DependencyService {

    /**
     * Getters for the Configuration settings
     */
    get SomeSetting(): number { return 1; }

}

@Injectable()
export class ParentService {

    constructor(private readonly Config_: DependencyService) {}

    /**
     * Getters for the Configuration settings
     */
    get Setting(): number {
        return this.Config_.SomeSetting;
    }

}
```

The test file then shows the error:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { createMock } from '@golevelup/ts-jest';

import { ParentService, DependencyService } from './service';

describe('ParentService', () => {
    let service: ParentService;
    let TestConfig: DependencyService;

    afterEach( () => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const mockDependency = createMock<DependencyService>();

        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                ParentService,
                { provide: DependencyService, useValue: mockDependency },
            ],
        })
            .useMocker(createMock)
            .compile();

        service = module.get<ParentService>(ParentService);
        TestConfig = module.get<DependencyService>(DependencyService);
    });

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should have the configuration defined', () => {
        expect(TestConfig).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should get the proper value from the dependency', () => {
        // expect(TestConfig.SomeSetting).toBe(1);
        jest.spyOn(TestConfig, 'SomeSetting', 'get').mockReturnValueOnce(2).mockReturnValue(3);
        expect(TestConfig.SomeSetting).toBe(2);
        expect(TestConfig.SomeSetting).toBe(3);
        expect(TestConfig.SomeSetting).toBe(3);
    });

    it('should validate the getters values for testing', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(TestConfig, 'SomeSetting', 'get').mockReturnValue(5);
        expect(service.Setting).toBe(5);
    });

    it('should use the local value', () => {
        jest.spyOn(service, 'Setting', 'get').mockReturnValue(12);
        expect(service.Setting).toBe(12);
    });
});
```

This causes the error to be: `Error: Property SomeSetting does not have access type get`

The default createMock() does not seem to create the getters.

**Updated test file** with Jay McDoniel comment:

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { createMock } from '@golevelup/ts-jest';
import { ParentService, DependencyService} from './service';

describe('ParentService', () => {
    let service: ParentService;
    let TestConfig: DependencyService;

    afterEach( () => {
        jest.clearAllMocks();
    });

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            providers: [
                ParentService,
            ],
        })
            .useMocker((value) => createMock(value))
            .compile();

        service = module.get<ParentService>(ParentService);
        TestConfig = module.get<DependencyService>(DependencyService);
    });

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should have the configuration defined', () => {
        expect(TestConfig).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should get the proper value from the dependency', () => {
        jest.spyOn(TestConfig, 'SomeSetting', 'get').mockReturnValueOnce(2).mockReturnValue(3);
        expect(TestConfig.SomeSetting).toBe(2);
        expect(TestConfig.SomeSetting).toBe(3);
        expect(TestConfig.SomeSetting).toBe(3);
    });

    it('should validate the getters values for testing', async () => {
        jest.spyOn(TestConfig, 'SomeSetting', 'get').mockReturnValue(5);
        expect(service.Setting).toBe(5);
    });

    it('should use the local value', () => {
        jest.spyOn(service, 'Setting', 'get').mockReturnValue(12);
        expect(service.Setting).toBe(12);
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show in your code and test where you mock this `TimeEntryEditableDays`? I see your code and test referencing `TimeEntryMinimumHours`, but that's not what the error is referring to, right?

Comment: Sorry, TimeEntryEditableDays was a typo from copying over parts of the code. It is just another setting.  To your direct question though, AppService uses NestJS ConfigService to read the end in `LoadApplicationConfiguration_()`  which is shown.  The AppService also has the getter `TimeEntryMinimumHours`.  The TimeEntryService then has a getter `MinimumHours` which returns the `TimeEntryMinimumHours` getter from AppService (ConfigurationDataService_ in the code)

Comment: I think this is how `createMock`is being used. Can you try `.useMocker((value) => createMock(value))`? I think it has to do with how proxies work under the hood

Comment: Unfortunately I get the error `SomeSetting property does not exist` with the change.  Updated test file in the original question, which should have the .useMocker() code line you suggested.

Comment: Hmm, did using `createMock` directly (i.e. not using `useMocker`) work? If so could you get a link to show this behavior? I'd definitely like to look more into it

Comment: https://github.com/Chowarmaan/createMock.git

Comment: Did my repository help at all? Should I create an issue on Go Level Up, for the get.  Functions appear to work correctly, but the getter does not.

Comment: I think this might be a `Proxy` implementation limitation. For your reproduction please add a `package.json`, `tsconfig`, and proper configuration setup so the golevelup team can easily clone, install, and run the reproduction without taking extra steps,